# make permalink go to a custom single.php file

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, templates, template-redirect

hope somebody can help me with this because I am struggling for a while. 
I want to use two single.php on my website, one to display the regular posts and another to display some products that I will style different then the posts. I duplicated the single.php and named it products.php but I cannot figure out how to make the permalink grab my products.php and not the single.php. 
Please, is there a way to accomplish this? Thank you very much!

Comment: what differentiates a product from a regular post?

Comment: The product will have a gallery and the text will be displayed different then the post, I need to add featured products bellow and I have to disable comments. Thanks!

Comment: I meant in terms of how WordPress would know which template to load, what defines a product as such versus a regular post?

Comment: I used this function in my functions.php `add_filter('single_template', create_function(
 '$the_template',
 'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) {
  if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php") )
  return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php"; }
 return $the_template;' )`

Comment: ok, "category" was the answer I was looking for. so this is solved then? add your solution as an answer if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, Milo, the function works fine but a problem never comes alone :(, so my issue now is that I need to use that template for all my categories and I am not sure if in the end it is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a custom post type (named "products") and rename your single.php file to single-products.php. It should be much easier like this.

The plugin below (free) should help you create a custom post type without any coding.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-maker/

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me, Ciprian. I will try what you suggested me but I hoped I can solve it with permalinks. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding in my function.php this function:

```
add_filter('single_template',
    create_function(
        '$the_template',
        'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) {
            if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php") ) {
                return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php";
            }
        }
        return $the_template;'
    )
);
```

and naming my second single.php with the slug name. Here's [the tutorial I followed](http://designisphilosophy.com/tutorials/creating-custom-single-post-templates/). Thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

in your product.php page add this on top

```
/*
Template Name: anYtemplatEnamE
*/
```

and then from admin section you will assign this `anYtemplatEnamE` template to any page.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me, I am new with WordPress and I used categories, instead of pages. Is there a different solution if I used categories? Thank you!

Comment: sorry i dint get you .

Comment: As I said, I am new with WordPress and I try to explain as best I can, hope I am not upseting you. So, to list my products, I used <php wp_list_categories(); ?>. From my category.php, I need to link the products to a different single.php then the one it displays posts. Thank you!